# Placing ggplot2 shape annotations into titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, shapes, subtitle

I am trying to insert a shape (and fill color) into a title/subtitle, but cannot find the syntax to do so:

```
    library(tidyverse) 
    D <-diamonds %>%  filter(color=="D") %>%sample_frac(0.1) 
    G <-diamonds %>%  filter(color=="G") %>% sample_frac(0.1)

    ggplot(D, aes(x=carat, y=price))+  
    geom_jitter(data=G)+geom_point(shape=6)+
      geom_jitter(data=D)+geom_point(shape=22, fill='red')+
     labs(title, "This is a title", 
    subtitle= 
    "D diamonds (insert shape 22 fill red) and G diamonds (shape 6 color black)",
     caption = "what I want is to insert the shape and fill color into the (sub)title")
```

Suggestions? Annotate seem designed to work only in the plot-space.

Comment: Could you make and move a legend up to the top left under the title as a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

A possible work-around from working with images is to use a legend to get the look you want.  This involves first making a legend.  I used the `color` aesthetic to make the legend, one for each points layer.  The strings I give in `aes` will be the label legends.

I modify the legend via `scale_color_manual`.  This involves getting the labels in the right order and setting the colors.  In addition I use `guide_legend` options to move the labels to the left of the key boxes (they default to the right) and get the right shapes and fills for the points.

Then, in `theme`, the legend can be moved to the top left, the key boxes can be filled with white instead of grey and reduced in size, and the space around the legend can be reduced.

This all looks like:

```
ggplot(D, aes(x = carat, y = price))+  
     geom_jitter(data = G) +
     geom_point(data = G, aes(color = "and G diamonds"), shape = 6) +
     geom_jitter() +
     geom_point(aes(color = "D diamonds"), shape = 22, fill='red') +
     labs(title = "This is a title") +
     scale_color_manual(name = NULL, values = c("black", "black"), 
                        limits = c("D diamonds", "and G diamonds"),
                        guide = guide_legend(label.position = "left",
                                             override.aes = list(shape = c(22, 6),
                                                                 fill = c("red", "black")) ) ) +
     theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",
           legend.position = "top",
           legend.justification = "left",
           legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
           legend.key.size = unit(.5, "mm"),
           legend.margin = margin(b = 0, 0, 0, 0) )
```

[image]

Starting in the [current development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) of ggplot2, *ggplot2_2.1.0.9001*, there is a `legend.box.spacing` option in `theme` to reduce the space between the plot and the legend.  I thought `legend.box.spacing = unit(2, "mm")` looked pretty good.

Comment: That's elegant! Rather than my approach - essentially cheating and trying to sneak the legend into the title by stealth, you propose to simply move  the legend into the subtitle space.  Clever!  Many ways to skin the cat.